# Sooner than If sentence structure

Tags: meaning

Can anyone help me with this sentence?

After a female dolphin loses her calf, she can give birth again much sooner than if her calf had matured to adulthood.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: I cannot understand why there is had in it

Comment: The calf has died. Had it lived on, the female dolphin couldn't have conceived sooner... is what is meant. Of course, you need _had_ there.

Answer (score 1):

The "if" clause is basically the protasis of a third conditional. It is used to describe a past situation that did not actually occur, and it requires the past tense of "to have" along with a past participle (in this case, "had matured"). The UNC Writing Center describes this construction [as follows](https://writingcenter.unc.edu/tips-and-tools/conditionals-verb-tense-in-if-clauses/):

> This conditional deals with situations in the *past* that are unreal—they didn’t happen. We can still imagine what the consequences would have been. . . . When the situation is unreal and in the past, use past perfect (had + -ed) in the conditional clause and would have + verb in the main clause.

In case you're wondering what happened to the apodosis, it has been omitted. We could include it thus:

> After a female dolphin loses her calf, she can give birth again much sooner than **she would have** if her calf had matured to adulthood.